# OptaPlanner overconstrained planning does not set back to null

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm working with OptaPlanner and am using a HardMediumSoft score and nullable PlanningVariable to achieve over-constrained planning.

What I've noticed is that during CH phase, which I have left as default, it seems like usually all but maybe a few PlanningEntity will get a Planning Value set.

Then during LS phase, which is also default, I've forced my problem facts to force a failed hard constraint, with weight. Eventually, I get a score update, with a strong hard penalty.

So, the medium score at the beginning of LS is very close to zero. The hard score then goes very negative. I was expecting that after a hard score step is done, that OptaPlanner would make moves to un-assign Planning Values, as to satisfy the hard constraint. I've been working on this for weeks now, and have never seen the medium score go more negative.

Am I missing something here? Is this an inherit problem with how i've interpreted score levels?

Comment: Could you please explain the constraint about max 3 entities assigned to planning values? Are the entities perhaps organized into groups that must not be bigger than 3?

Comment: Yeah, I described that poorly. That part was not really relevant. Let me update... By coincidence, I do have a grouping pattern. All though that's another issue i'm trying to resolve. For this question, i'm mainly just interested in planning values being set back to null because of a hard constraint. It never seems to go backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a [nullable planning variable](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#nullablePlanningVariable), OptaPlanner will add `null` to the relevant value range to make it one of the possible values assignable to the variable.

In case you calculate the score via `ConstraintStreams` API, make sure you use [`forEachIncludingNullVars()`](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/constraint-streams/constraint-streams.html#constraintStreamsForEach) instead of `forEach()` in every constraint that works with a nullable planning variable

It may be worth [investigating logs](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2021/05/06/ThePathToOptaPlannerEnlightenmentStartsInTheLog.html) to see whether any such unassigning moves are generated and evaluated (trace level logging) and if so, whether they are selected as a step (debug level logging)

Comment: I was deceived. Looks like it is making moves back to null, I just never toggled trace logs to see it. Thanks. I've got a hundred other OptaPlanner configuration questions to figure out now